# Combine two lists of indices to create a 1-1 mapping between two other lists

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations, indices

We'll start with the example.

I have two lists:

```
segments = [16, 19, 22, 26]
labels = [horse, cow, mule]
```

These two lists has a prefers (in order) some of the elements in the other list as shown in the tables below. Note that a segment can think that it should have a certain label, while the corresponding label doesn't think it should have that segment.

```
       | Preferred Label                 | Preferred Segment
       | (in order, L -> R)              | (in order, L -> R)
    ---+-------------------        ------+-------------------
    16 | horse, cow, mule          horse | 26, 19, 22, 16
    19 | horse, mule               cow   | 16, 22, 19
    22 | mule, cow, horse          mule  | 26, 22, 19
    26 | mule
```

which can be expressed in the form of two index lists:

```
// We have 4 segments, each have a ranked list (length 0-3) of preferred label
labelIndicesForSegments = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 2], [2, 1, 0], [2]] 

// We have 3 labels, each have a ranked list (length 0-4) of preferred segment
segmentIndicesForLabels = [[3, 1, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Now, how do I create the "optimal 1 to 1 mapping" between segments and labels? I.e., the segments gets a label as much to the left as possible in its table, and vice versa. The algorithm should force pairs even if a segment and a label doesn't have each other in their preference list (this, however, should be avoided as far as possible).

I do not know what would be the best answer to the example above. Some answers could be

```
1: [(16, horse), (19, mule), (22, cow)]
2: [(16, cow), (19, horse), (26, mule)]
3: [(19, horse), (22, cow), (26, mule)]
```

But how do I choose what segment will be without a matching label? And how do I compute which one is the most optimal?

As you can see pretty much everything can vary. Segments and labels doesn't have to be of equal length and the list of indices doesn't have to be of equal length. While algorithm speed always matters I can say that in this case I won't be working with more than 10-20 elements in either segments or labels.

My problem is that I have no entry point on how to solve this. Most likely there is an algorithm to solve this but I don't know it's name. I'm also implementing this in Java, in case you want to make a concrete non-pseudocode example ;)

Comment: It's not clear what you need to accomplish. Please post the expected answer for your sample with the explanation.

Comment: I would create a table holding the sum of the preferences and then select for every row the element with higher preference sum available. Hope this help!

Comment: If there is a one to one correspondence between the segments and the labels, then can you explain how segmentIndicesForLabels first element would include the segment 3?  Element 3 in labelIndicesForSegments only contains the index of 2.  So, shouldn't element 2 in segmentIndicesForLabels contain only 2 and 1?  Likewise, element 1 in segmentIndicesForLabels should not contain element 1 since 1 does not appear in labelIndicesForSegments for that element.  If this is not right, then could you edit the question and explain the problem better.

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify a lot of things. Hopefully it should be more understandable now. @BobBryan The 1-1 correspondence doesn't need to exist from the start, but it can be enforced if it comes to that.

Comment: Ok.  That helps clear some things up.  I was wondering what does your input look like.  Is it perhaps a list of segments with a list of labels for each of those segments, along with a list of segments with a list of labels for those segments?  As for the output containers, how do you want to process this data later?  All at once, or random access?  When you say "how do I compute which one is the most optimal?" - what do you mean?  Do you mean the segment with the least number of labels in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is called the stable marriage problem

The idea of the algorithm to solve such a problem is that each of your segments will successively be assigned to the next label on its preference list that is not already assigned to a segment it prefers.

This will converge towards an optimal matching (note that there can be more than one).

Here is a java example (I didn't test it that much, use at your own risk ;) )

```
class SMP {
  static int[] segments = {16, 19, 22, 26};
  static String[] labels = {"horse", "cow", "mule"};

  static int[][] labelIndicesForSegments = {{0, 1, 2}, {0, 2}, {2, 1, 0}, {2}};
  static int[][] segmentIndicesForLabels = {{3, 1, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 1}};

  static int[] matching = new int[segments.length];
  static int[] nextLabel = new int[segments.length]; // A simple pointer to the next label to test for each segment (the current position in its own preference list) 

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // initialize all matchings
    for (int i=0; i<matching.length; i++) {  
      matching[i] = -1;
      nextLabel[i] = 0;
    }

    // While there is at least one free label and one free segment  
    while (canEnhance()) {
      int unmatched = findUnmatchedSegment(); // Pick an unmatched segment
      int label = labelIndicesForSegments[unmatched][nextLabel[unmatched]];

      nextLabel[unmatched]++;

      int matchedSegment = getMatchedSegment(label);

      if (matchedSegment == -1) { // The label is not matched
        matching[unmatched] = label;
      } else {
        if (labelPrefersSegment(label, matchedSegment, unmatched)) {
          matching[unmatched] = label;
          matching[matchedSegment] = -1;
        }
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < matching.length; i++) {
                if (matching[i] != -1)
                  System.out.println("Segment "+segments[i]+" matched with label "+labels[matching[i]]);
              }
      System.out.println("-----");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matching.length; i++) {
      if (matching[i] != -1)
        System.out.println("Segment "+segments[i]+" matched with label "+labels[matching[i]]);
    }
  }

  public static boolean labelPrefersSegment(int label, int currentSegment, int newSegment) {
    int[] preferenceList = segmentIndicesForLabels[label];

    for (int i = 0; i < preferenceList.length; i++) {
      if (preferenceList[i] == currentSegment) return false;
      if (preferenceList[i] == newSegment) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static int getMatchedSegment(int label) {
    for (int i=0; i<matching.length; i++) {
      if (matching[i] == label) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }

  public static int findUnmatchedSegment() {
    for (int i=0; i<matching.length; i++) {
      // The segment need to be free and to still have labels to test
      if (matching[i] == -1 && nextLabel[i] < labelIndicesForSegments[i].length) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }

  public static boolean canEnhance() {
    return findUnmatchedSegment() != -1;
  }
}
```

You could do better using a more object-oriented approach but that's a start :)

The essential part is in the while loop, the small functions after the main are not that interesting :)

You can find more infos there : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem

Cheers